# Can you use conditionals in IMAP_SEARCH from the PHP IMAP library?

Tags: php, email, imap

I haven't been able to find anything while exploring the code and searching for documentation.  Has anyone been able to achieve this?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't.  (Hard to believe, right?)

PHP uses Mark Crispin's c-client library under the hood to do its IMAP work.  In the c-client library, there is a deprecated method `mail_criteria` in `mail.c` that translates an IMAP search string to a c-client search program.  `mail_criteria` [has been deprecated for the past 8 years or so and, as such, was never updated to support the IMAP4 search syntax](http://www.mail-archive.com/c-client@u.washington.edu/msg00252.html).  So search terms like `OR` that weren't present in IMAP2 never got support in the `mail_criteria` function.  Here's all the terms it supports starting with an '`O`':

```
  case 'O':                 /* possible OLD, ON */
    if (!strcmp (criterion+1,"LD")) f = pgm->old = T;
    else if (!strcmp (criterion+1,"N"))
      f = mail_criteria_date (&pgm->on,&r);
    break;
```

`OR` isn't on that list.  So even though the c-client supports `OR` in its `SEARCHPGM` structs, it doesn't parse `OR` in the deprecated `mail_criteria` function.

And [PHP still uses `mail_criteria` to parse search queries](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53182#1299783097).  In 2011.  So until either the c-client library un-deprecates `mail_criteria` and makes it IMAP4-compliant or PHP writes its own IMAP search parser, you are stuck with whatever IMAP2 supported.  [Which doesn't include `OR`.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1176#page-16)