# imap_search search all failed deliveries

Tags: php, imap

how to search all emails that bounced?

i tried this. `imap_search($inbox,"SUBJECT failed")`
but it could not match those that has different subject like "undeliverable" ,"postmaster" etc

Comment: is there a way to put OR in the code so it could also include undeliverable and postmaster

Comment: [Not in php, unfortunately.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264051/can-you-use-conditionals-in-imap-search-from-the-php-imap-library)  You'd have to run separate `imap_search` calls and merge the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those emails should all have a header that looks like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/report;
    boundary="----_=_NextPart_001_01C4E545.613B5900";
    report-type=delivery-status
```

So to find them, you need to issue an IMAP command like:

```
A001 SEARCH HEADER Content-Type multipart/report HEADER Content-Type
 report-type=delivery-status
```

Unfortunately, php's `imap_search` doesn't allow you to issue a `HEADER` search, as far as I know.  So you're probably stuck trying to patch together `SUBJECT` terms...